# Translate mongodb aggregate query into Java/Kotlin Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data

So I came up with a query that I'm not really sure how to translate into Spring Data. This is the query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$field",
            count: {
                $sum: "$count"
            },
            data: {
                "$addToSet": "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            count: -1
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 10
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$data"
    }
])
```

The problematic part is `unwind`. In this raw query I'm putting the original document("$$ROOT") that is being processed into `data`, so after the set is being processed I can just unwind it and end up with just the documents that I really want. This works fine from the shell. The problem is that I'm not seeing how to do the same operation in Java/Kotlin, I can just add to the set without having a way to reference that data later. Could someone help me out and write how this would look in Java/Kotlin with Spring Data?

Comment: Did you try using the MongoDB Compass utility to transform the queries to any programming language? You can load your aggregation function there and export it to Java.

Comment: Never heard of it, will take a look into that.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/export-pipeline-to-language)

Comment: I know how to do it in spring, but i dont know about kotlin. can you use `mongoTemplate` in kotlin? I can answer you if its spring oot

Comment: @varman yeah please just write it in java. I am using mongotemplate with kotlin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
public List<Object> test() {

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        
        group("field")
            .sum("count").as("count")
            .addToSet("$$ROOT").as("data"),
        sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "count"),
        limit(10),
        unwind("data")

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();

}
```